# What is the regex pattern to be used with AKS allowed container images built-in policy?

Tags: azure, azure-aks, azure-policy

I am using the AKS cluster. I have enabled the Policy add-on feature. And have assigned the built-in policy with definition name **Kubernetes cluster containers should only use allowed images**

During the assignment, I have included the allowed regex pattern as ***^.+mcr.microsoft.com/.+$***
This is the image source I have included in my Pod YAML "mcr.microsoft.com/v2/mcr/hello-world/tags/list" But it gets denied. Since I am not familiar with the Regex pattern kindly help me to use the right input.

Comment: try to remove the first `.+` So: `^mcr.microsoft.com/.+$`

Comment: Actually mcr.microsoft.com\/.+$ helped me to achieve the pattern

Comment: glad to hear it. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the first `.+` from your pattern. So `^mcr.microsoft.com\/.+$`

This means that the image name actually starts exactly with "mcr.microsoft.com..."

Comment: No please edit your answer since I am unable to do it. The / needs \ as an escape sequence. So your answer should mention that as well. Mention mcr.microsoft.com\/.+$

Comment: good point! edited