# Regex for azure kubernetes policy doesn't work

Tags: regex, azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks

I'm trying to configure a policy called "Kubernetes cluster containers should only use allowed images". The policy is installed with terraform:

```
  policy_definition_reference {
    policy_definition_id = "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/policyDefinitions/febd0533-8e55-448f-b837-bd0e06f16469"
    reference_id = "Kubernetes cluster containers should only use allowed images"
    parameter_values = <<VALUE
     {
        "effect": {"value": "[parameters('policyEffect')]"},
        "allowedContainerImagesRegex":  {"value": "[parameters('allowedContainerImagesRegex')]"}
      } 

      VALUE
}
```

The actual parameters provided in json config files for each given azure subscription. It works properly this way for all other polices we have.

My regex for **allowedContainerImagesRegex** is:

```
  "allowedContainerImagesRegex": {
    "value": "^([^\\/]+\\.azurecr\\.io|quay\\.io|ghcr\\.io|mcr\\.microsoft\\.com|rapid7|pypiserver|selenium|rancher|flux|pypiserver)\\/.+$"
  }
```

it seems to be working for azurecr, as the policy compliance report doesn't contain any images installed from our azure container registries. However, it doesn't work for all other registries, for example, it complains about `pypiserver/pypiserver:latest`, which allegedly should be covered by the above regex.

What is interesting, is that the **azure defender** complains even about images from *azure container registry* too, as if it is not based upon the same policy compliance results.

Honestly, I can't wrap my head around this problem, any suggestions appreciated.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: may be due to the regex pattern you are using for the allowedContainerImagesRegex parameter. The regex pattern you provided seems to be working for Azure Container Registry, but not for other registries.

Comment: do you see where the problem with regex is? I'm using pipe (I) for OR, then followed by slash at the end of string, escaped by 2 slashes, as required for json, followed by anything. e.g. pypiserver)\\/.+$

Comment: Hmm, your regex seems to be correct for matching image names from various registries according to the pattern you've specified, I checked, the image pypiserver/pypiserver:latest is indeed matched by your regex

Comment: thanks @Arko There seems to be a related post, but I guess, it doesn't shed light on my problem either: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72274124/what-is-the-regex-pattern-to-be-used-with-aks-allowed-container-images-built-in?rq=2